# fscanf read()s more than the number of characters I asked for

Tags: c, stdio

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  unsigned char c;

  setbuf(stdin, NULL);
  scanf("%2hhx", &c);
  printf("%d\n", (int)c);
  return 0;
}
```

I set `stdin` to be unbuffered, then ask `scanf` to read up to 2 hex characters. Indeed, `scanf` does as asked; for example, having compiled the code above as `foo`:

```
$ echo 23 | ./foo
35
```

However, if I `strace` the program, I find that libc actually read 3 characters. Here is a partial log from strace:

```
$ echo 234| strace ./foo
read(0, "2", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "3", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "4", 1)                         = 1
35 # prints the correct result
```

So sscanf is giving the expected result. However, this extra character being read is detectable, and it happens to break the communications protocol I am trying to implement (in my case, GDB remote debugging).

The man page for sscanf says about the field width:

> Reading of characters stops either when this maximum is reached or when a nonmatching character is found, whichever happens first.

This seems a bit deceptive, at least; or is it in fact a bug? Is it too much to hope that with unbuffered stdin, scanf might read no more than the amount of input I asked for?

(I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04 with glibc 2.27; I've not tried this on other systems.)

Comment: I would interpret "reading" in the man page as being with respect to the C stream; that is, the characters after the first 2 remain available to be read by `scanf`, `getc`, `fread`, and the like.

Comment: I think [POSIX 2.5.1](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05_01) allows for this: "It is implementation-defined whether, and under what conditions, all input is seen exactly once."

Comment: @NateEldredge this comment refers to the pair of file handles created by "fork".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This seems a bit deceptive, at least; or is it in fact a bug?

IMO, no.

> An input item is read from the stream, ... An input item is defined as the  longest sequence of input characters which does not exceed any specified field width and which is, or is a prefix of, a matching input sequence. **The first character,  if any , after the input item remains unread.** If the length of the input item is zero, the execution of the directive fails; this condition is a matching failure unless end-of-file, an encoding error, or a read error prevented input from the stream, in which case it is an input failure.  C17dr § 7.21.6.2 9

Code such as `"%hhx"` (without a width limit) certainly must get 1 past the hex characters to know it is done.  That excess character is *pushed-back* into `stdin` for the next input operation.

The "The first character, if any, after the input item remains unread" implies to me then a disassociation of reading characters from the stream at the lowest level and reading characters from the stream as a *stream* can *pushed-back* at least 1 character and consider that as "remains unread".  The width limit of 2 does not save code as 3 characters can be read from the *stream* and 1 pushed back.

The width of 2  limits the maximum length of bytes to interpret, not a limit of the number of characters read at the lowest level.

> Is it too much to hope that with unbuffered stdin, scanf might read no more than the amount of input I asked for?

Yes.  If buffered or not, I think as a *stream* like `stdin` allows *pushed-back* of characters to consider them unread.

Anyways, `"%2hhx"` is brittle to expect not more than 2 characters read given leading white-space do not count. "These white-space characters are not counted against a specified field width."

---

The "I set stdin to be unbuffered" does not stop a *stream* from reading an excess character and later pushing it back.

---

Given "this extra character being read is detectable, and it happens to break the communications protocol" I recommend a new approach that does not use a *stream*.